# Elegant javascript for hiding and showing divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My javascript is the weakest of my front-end web  knowledge and I assume that's a much more efficient way to achieve my functionality than how I've done it.

Basically, I have a site where you have some `<li>` items and when clicked they show a particular div and if another div (linked to another `<li>` item) is currently visible it hides it and shows its respective div. It also assigns an `active` class to the `<li>` item to provide a different coloured icon for the active section (standard UX practice).

Here's my HTML and Javascript function.

```
    <li id="general">General</li>
    <li id="blog">Blog</li>
    <li id="twitter">Twitter</li>
```

And the javascript (it hurts just looking at it)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#general").addClass("active");

$("#general").click(function() {
    $(".data-tab").hide();
    $(".settings-general").toggle();
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#general").addClass("active");
});

$(".settings-twitter").hide();

$("#twitter").click(function() {
    $(".data-tab").hide();
    $(".settings-twitter").toggle();
    $("li").removeClass("active");      
    $("#twitter").addClass("active");
});

$(".settings-blog").hide();

$("#blog").click(function() {
    $(".data-tab").hide();
    $(".settings-blog").toggle();
    $("li").removeClass("active");      
    $("#blog").addClass("active");
})

});
```

Don't get me wrong it works well! But it just looks exhausting and there's probably a much quicker way jQuery can achieve this. Any advice for a JS beginner?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: can you post a fiddle? or the rest of your html? The full structure of your code would help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a single function to accomplish the same thing twice, or you could just loop over the code for each you wish to setup.

```
function setUp(name){
    $(".settings-"+name).hide();

    $("#"+name).click(function() {
        $(".data-tab").hide();
        $(".settings-"+name).toggle();
        $("li").removeClass("active");      
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
}

setUp('blog');
setUp('twitter');
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you. I added some code to `setUp('general')` to assign the functionality of the method to the general settings div but then added `$('settings-general').show();` to show the general settings by default. I'll accept answer once time has elapsed! :)

Comment: With jQuery you would normally try to avoid repeated calls. If you restructure using `data-` attributes you do not need to change the code for any number of items (alternate answer posted).

Answer (score 2):

Data-drive the whole thing using `data-` attributes on the options. The same code then works on any number of items without changes to code:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/8hvofd6m/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu:first").addClass("active");
    $('.settings-general').show();
    $(".menu").click(function () {

        var $active = $(this);

        // Unhilight the inactive items
        $(".menu").not($active).removeClass("active");

        // Then highlight just the active item
        $active.addClass("active");

        // Seek the target using a jQuery selector in the data-setting attribute
        var $setting = $($active.data('setting'));

        // Hide the others
        $('.settings').not($setting).hide();

        // Show the selected one
        $setting.show();
    });
});
```

The `data-setting` attributes can be any selector, class, id or complex. so you can do cool stuff like:

```
<li class="menu" data-setting="#info .subinfo:first">First info</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a single class on a parent container and use css to hide the elements, something like:

```
<style>
    div.tab { display: none }

    body.general li.general { font-weight: bold; }
    body.general div.tab.general { display: block; }

    body.blog li.blog { font-weight: bold; }
    body.blog div.tab.blog { display: block; }

    body.twitter li.twitter { font-weight: bold; }
    body.twitter div.tab.twitter { display: block; }
</style>

<body>
    <ul>
      <li class="general">General</li>
      <li class="blog">Blog</li>
      <li class="twitter">Twitter</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="general tab">general tab</div>
    <div class="blog tab">blog tab</div>
    <div class="twitter tab">twitter tab</div>

    <script>
        $('li').click(function () {
            $('body').attr('class', $(this).attr('class'));
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/szzdyp1n/ for a working example.

Comment: The `div`s and `li`s don't have to be in the order I have written them, they can be an any order. I'll move them around.

Comment: Better now with your edits, and does work, but replacing all classes at the `body` still *smells wrong*. You are moving a logic problem to become a styling problem. Maybe its just my deep loathing of the CSS "standard" but this seems harder to maintain and would only work for one plugin at a time (as it wipes out all classes on `body`).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: In practise I wouldn't do this on the body, I'd do this on the nearest container. It does suffer from making the styling horrible to maintain, it's not suitable if there will be a lot of entries.

Comment: +1 because you *know* it is a bad idea, but this technique *is* another tool in the toolbox and does work :)